# server not sending email with virtuemart order status change

Tags: php, memory, memory-management, joomla, virtuemart

I have an interesting problem. I have installed my `Joomla 2.5` and `Virtuemart 2.0` software properly as I have over a dozen times before. I was testing it on my live server and noticed I cannot send any email confirmations or notifications. This is weird because I haven't done anything with the code. 
Here are my server settings:

- Apache version 2.2.23
- PHP version  5.2.17
- MySQL version 5.0.96-community

I tried asking support but they don't seem to know what the issue is and simply blames Virtuemart's control panel.

Another thing is that it saves the data in the database but if I submit the form to notify my customer of an order status the page returns blank, but no email is sent.

The same exact setup is working on my local computer. Is there anything that I should ask my server provider to check for?

Here is what the error is saying on the blank page

```
Strict Standards: Declaration of JParameter::loadSetupFile() should be compatible with that of JRegistry::loadSetupFile() in /myDirectory/libraries/joomla/html/parameter.php on line 512

Strict Standards: Declaration of plgVMPaymentPayzen::emptyCart() should be compatible with that of vmPSPlugin::emptyCart() in /myDirectory/vmpayment/payzen/payzen.php on line 833

Strict Standards: Declaration of plgVMPaymentSystempay::emptyCart() should be compatible with that of vmPSPlugin::emptyCart() in /myDirectory/plugins/vmpayment/systempay/systempay.php on line 833

Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 33554432 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 491520 bytes) in /myDirectory/libraries/tcpdf/tcpdf.php on line 21792
```

Comment: can you enable php errors? blank page seems to suggest some php error.

Answer (score 0):

that last error message is probably your culprit. looks like you may have a runaway script that's eating memory (which email scripts can do if you're not careful). you can increase memory for that script by adding this line at the top of the PHP file:

```
ini_set("memory_limit","12M");
```

"12M" can be a greater number if need be. HOWEVER, increasing the memory is not the best solution. Would be better to find the offending code and optimize it.

Comment: ok thank you...my directory where I was holding my joomla has mysteriously been deleted after I had asked them what was going on with their server...I will try this out and let you know the results.

Comment: ok, I am still getting the same error message. I looked at my server settings and the maximum I'm allowed to put is 32M. the file is trying to run 33554432 bytes. Any other suggestions?